# ASP.NET MVC Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this code repeated many times in my page

```
<div>
  <span>text</span><br />
  <span>text1</span><select></select><span>text2</span>
  <input/>                  
</div>
```

I dont want to write it every time 
how can i box it in MVC and pass parameters to it?

Comment: Are you using a master page on your site?

Answer (score 3):

you could create an HTML helper that returns that HTML

something like the below:

```
using System;
namespace MvcApplication1.Helpers
{
          public class LabelHelper

          {
               public static string Label(string target, string text)
               {
                    return String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text);
               }
          }
}
```

Comment: In addition... From view you must write @Html.Raw(LabelHelper.Label("df","dff")) to understand that code like html.

Answer (score 2):

You can create partial view and have a ViewModel which has all those information which you are showing. Wherever you want to use this content, call the partial view with the ViewModel.

```
@model MyBoxContent
<div>
  <span>@Model.Text1</span><br />
  <span>@Model.Text1</span><select></select><span>@Model.Text2</span>
  <input/>                  
</div>
```

and have a view model called "MyBoxContent"

```
 public class MyBoxContent
 {
        public string Text1{ set; get; }
        public string Text2{ set; get; }
 }
```

Have this ViewModel as the property of your other ViewModel from where you want to show and call the Partial View with that.

```
 @Html.Partial("BoxData", Model.MyBoxContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can use a partialView and just render it.

```
@Html.Partial("SomePartialView", DataYouPlanOnPassingIn)
```

also don't forget to put your model at the top of the partial view so you can start using it:

```
@model System.String
```